# Why is a custom cell's label only appearing when a row is selected?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am currently working on an app, in which I have a list of devices based on JSON, and created some custom cells for specific device types. My code sorts the devices just fine and sets the labels of the cells to the device name, I already checked that. The cellIdentifiers are correct, too. My table view contains a cell from the class ZWDeviceItem, so it should load properly since all classes like ZWDeviceItemSwitch are subclasses. I load my custom cells via NIBs.

My problem is, that the labels in those custom cells are not visible until you select a specific row. I set the IBOutlets for my tableview and linked the label to the custom cells.The cell height is more than sufficient and everything is displayed correctly when I select a row.

Code to set the device type:

```
@class ZWDevice;

@interface ZWDeviceItem : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *refreshingImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameView;

- (void)setDisplayName:(ZWDevice*)device;

@end

#import "ZWDeviceItem.h"
#import "ZWDevice.h"

@implementation ZWDeviceItem

@synthesize nameView = _nameView;
@synthesize refreshingImage = _refreshingImage;

- (void)setDisplayName:(ZWDevice *)device
{
    NSDictionary *dict = device.metrics;
    self.nameView.text = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];
}

@end
```

Code to select which NIB to load:

```
- (ZWDeviceItem*)createUIforTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atPos:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ZWDeviceItem *item = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_deviceType];
    if (item == nil)
    {
        if ([_deviceType isEqualToString:@"probe"])
            //this method returns the NIB
            item = [ZWDeviceItemDimmer device];
        else if ([_deviceType isEqualToString:@"switchBinary"])
            item = [ZWDeviceItemSwitch device];
        else if ([_deviceType isEqualToString:@"switchMultilevel"])
            item = [ZWDeviceItemSensorMulti device];
        else if ([_deviceType isEqualToString:@"thermostat"])
            item = [ZWDeviceItemThermostat device];
        else if ([_deviceType isEqualToString:@"battery"])
            item = [ZWDeviceItemBattery device];
        else if ([_deviceType isEqualToString:@"fan"])
            item = [ZWDeviceItemSensorBinary device];
        else
            item = [[ZWDeviceItem alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:_deviceType];
    }

    return item;
}
```

and last but not least my CellForRowIndexPath method in the UIViewController (and yes, I have set the ViewController as delegate and datasource):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ZWDevice *device = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ZWDeviceItem *cell = [device createUIforTableView:tableView atPos:indexPath];
    [cell setDisplayName:device];

    return cell;
}
```

I would really appreciate help with this problem! I looked up several similar issues but could´t fix it yet. Most answers told me to check the linking but that works fine.

If you need any further information let me know and I will provide it.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

Here are the screenshots from the simulator:
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu39o.jpg)

### EDIT: Solved

Well, seems I was just too stupid for this one. The solution was to set the text color in the NIBs to something different than white… I set it to dark text color and now it gets displayed right away and beautifully.

Sorry for you guys who thought about a serious solution.

Comment: post the screenshot of selected cell

Comment: I would also question your design. You have a model object (device) responsible for creating a tableview cell - which is really the job of the controller in MVC as used by Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line here:

```
ZWDeviceItem *item = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_deviceType];
```

this will always return a valid item or create one if it can't return one. And it's using _deviceType before you are setting it, so it's using the value of whatever it is set to before.

Comment: I tested your recommendation but that wasn´t it. You were right, that the  
    if(item==nil)  
was unnecessary but the rest works fine. I get the correct NIBs loaded for the specific device type. The problem is that the label in the NIBs does´t get shown although it´s set correctly.
Anyway, thanks for your help!